# How to optimize rails insert query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

I am working on a ROR project with rails 4 and I have to write a rake task to read zipcodes from excel and bind these all zipcodes with deals. Excel contains 16k zipcodes. So, for each deal I have to create 16k records in the third table(deals_zipcodes).

I am using HABTM as follows:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
end
```

rake task:

```
task spectrum_deals: :environment do
    workbook =  Spreadsheet.open(Rails.root.join('public/zip_code_list.xls').to_path).worksheets.first
    deals = Deal.where(service_provider_id: ServiceProvider.where(name:"Spectrum").pluck(:id))
    zipcodes = Zipcode.where(code: workbook.rows.map{|a| a.to_a.first})
    deals.map{|deal| deal.zipcodes.delete_all }
    deals.each do |deal|
      deal.zipcodes << zipcodes
      puts "deal_id: #{deal.id} created"
    end
    puts "===============finished=============="
  end
```

This rake task works fine but at some point it raise memory issue and the system hangs.
Please provide me the solution how can I optimize it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are great gems around like [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) or [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) which make it simple to do these sorts of things, I'd strongly recommend using something like that.